# Fill missing values in list based on a condition

Tags: python, list

I will try to explain my issue with simple example. Let's say I've a list

```
lis = ['Elemnt-1' , 'Elemnt-2' , 'Elemnt-3' , '' , '' , 'Elemnt-6' , 'Elemnt-7']
```

How can I fill this missing values such that list will become.

```
lis = ['Elemnt-1' , 'Elemnt-2' , 'Elemnt-3' , 'Elemnt-2' , 'Elemnt-3' , 'Elemnt-6' , 'Elemnt-7']
```

**Explination with similar animation.**

[image]

I've figured out solution. Which is too inefficient for a l**onger lists & when I've multiple missing values**. Here is my logic

```
from itertools import accumulate

lis = ['Elemnt-1' , 'Elemnt-2' , 'Elemnt-3' , '' , '' , 'Elemnt-6' , 'Elemnt-7']

odd_index = lis[::2]
even_index = lis[1::2]

odd_index = list(accumulate(odd_index,lambda x, y: x if y is '' else y))
even_index = list(accumulate(even_index,lambda x, y: x if y is '' else y))

zipper = list(sum(zip(odd_index, even_index+[0]), ())[:-1])


print(zipper)
```

Given me #

```
['Elemnt-1', 'Elemnt-2', 'Elemnt-3', 'Elemnt-2', 'Elemnt-3', 'Elemnt-6', 'Elemnt-7']
```

I was looking for a **simpler elegant approach to solve this when there are multiple missing values in middle of list.**

**More examples:**

```
lis = ['Elemnt-1' , 'Elemnt-2' , 'Elemnt-3' , '' , '' , '' , 'Elemnt-7']
```

Need

```
lis = ['Elemnt-1' , 'Elemnt-2' , 'Elemnt-3' , 'Elemnt-1' , 'Elemnt-2' , 'Elemnt-3' , 'Elemnt-7']
```

Another example

```
lis = ['Elemnt-1' , 'Elemnt-2' , 'Elemnt-3' , '' , '' , 'Elemnt-6' , 'Elemnt-7', '']
```

Need

```
lis = ['Elemnt-1' , 'Elemnt-2' , 'Elemnt-3' , 'Elemnt-2' , 'Elemnt-3' , 'Elemnt-6' , 'Elemnt-7' , 'Elemnt-7']
```

**Logically n blank elements should be filled with n back elements**

Comment: Is it always 2 elements that you're expecting to be missing? What's the expected output if the missing elements are right at the start of the list?

Comment: `[item if item else lis[idx-lis.count('')] for idx, item in enumerate(lis)]`

Comment: Hi fab...Currently i'm not worried about ist starting with empty values...because, in all my cases i've seen anything...& i was worried about in future it may hav 2 or more missing values

Comment: @ILS nice, that works really neat. At least if there are only 1 set of consecutive missing values.

Comment: @ILS smart approch!! as FAB mentioned this logic works like a charm if I've only one set consequitive missing values

Answer (score 1):

Because you're looking 2 back to fill the empty spots, we skip the first 2 indeces as there's nothing before theme. Here I define a func that does this:

```
def filler(l: list):
    for i in range(2, len(l)):
        if l[i] == '':
            l[i] = l[i-2]
    return l

print(filler(['Elemnt-1' , 'Elemnt-2' , 'Elemnt-3' , '' , '' , 'Elemnt-6' , 'Elemnt-7']))
Out:
['Elemnt-1', 'Elemnt-2', 'Elemnt-3', 'Elemnt-2', 'Elemnt-3', 'Elemnt-6', 'Elemnt-7']
```

Comment: What If I've more than 2 missing values as I mentioned in last line of my question?

Comment: Updated case studies @cybergenik...

Comment: This should work as long as your missing values are not the first 2 indices. @Bhargav

Answer (score 1):

Using a list comprehension to replace empty values with value of this list two positions before. Repeats until no empty values left.

EDIT : after comments, it appears that it is not always 2 position before, but n blank elements should be filled with n elements before. Answer therefore is still missing something. Replacing `lis[index-2]` by  `lis[index-lis.count('')]` would not work because it is possible to have multiple set of empty spaces

```
filler = ['']*len(lis)
while '' in lis :
    filler = [lis[index-2] if value=="" else value for index, value in enumerate(lis)]
    print(filler)
    lis=filler

print(lis)
```

Comment: This only works If I've 2 missing values Anton...I've also added some more test cases below. this logic won't fits for those example..

Comment: My bad. Edited answer, tried a modification that repeats until there are no more empty space. But not sure thats's what you want, as it looks like you don't always need to remplace an empty with value two positions before ? Not sure, but does the offset depends on the number of consecutives empty ? E. g., two consecutives spaces mean choose value two positions before, one space mean chose value one before etc...

Comment: No i may have 1 empty space, 2 empty or 3 empty spaces...I've just counted all the possible spaces in my big list...max empty spaces are 3

Comment: But do you always choose the value two positions before an empty value, to replace this empty value ?

Comment: Logically n blank elements should be filled with n back elements. See some examples that I've attached at end of my question

Comment: Okay, you should add that in you question so thats it's clearer. My answer therefore still misses something

Answer (score 1):

You can determine the blank ranges first, then fill them with the previous items.

```py
lst = ['Elment-1' , 'Elment-2' , 'Elment-3' , '' , '' , 'Elment-6' , 'Elment-7', '']
lst_ext = ['p'] + lst + ['p']
# boundary of all blank ranges
blank_bound = [idx for idx, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(lst_ext, lst_ext[1:])) \
                   if (a == '' or b == '') and a != b] # [3, 5, 7, 8]
# fill each blank range
for l, r in zip(blank_bound[::2], blank_bound[1::2]):
    assert 2*l-r >= 0, "no enough items before the blank item"
    lst[l:r] = lst[2*l-r:l]
```

Comment: Logically, Make sense..This could actually work!!..Let me apply some examples..I will be right back!

Answer (score 0):

If the missing values are consecutive ones as you showed in the example you can use this.

```
def fillList(list):
    emptyCount = list.count('')
    for item in list:
        if item == '':
            list[list.index(item)] = list[list.index(item) - emptyCount]
    return list
```